# Using services by name from inside the cluster, but outside a pod

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have an nginx pod in the default namespace and a ClusterIP service exposing the pod.

```
$ kubectl run nginx-pod --image=nginx
$ kubectl expose po nginx-pod --name=nginx-service --port=8080 --target-port=80 --type=ClusterIP
```

I can access the service via its internal IP from inside the cluster.

```
$ kubectl get svc nginx-service
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
nginx-service   ClusterIP   10.100.5.218   <none>        8080/TCP   2m49s
$ wget -O- 10.100.5.218:8080
```

--> 200 OK

I can access the service by name from inside a pod.

```
$ kubectl run tmp -it --rm --image=busybox --command -- /bin/sh -c 'wget -O- nginx-service:8080'
```

--> 200 OK

However, why can't I access the service by name from outside a pod?

```
$ wget -O- nginx-service:8080
```

or

```
$ wget -O- nginx-service.default.svc.cluster.local:8080
```

--> `wget: unable to resolve host address ‘nginx-service’`

Comment: Where exactly is inside cluster but outside a pod? Are you running anything directly on the worker nodes? Why?

Comment: @Lukman I'm running a single node cluster for experimentation. `kubectl`/`wget` are executed on this machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magic service hostnames (and pod hostnames) are provided by the "cluster DNS" service, usually CoreDNS these days. A resolv.conf aimed at the internal CoreDNS is automatically injected into all pods. But I'm guessing by "outside of a pod" you mean on the underlying host which has no such entries in its resolv.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types
You either need NodePort or LoadBalancer service type.

Comment: Sorry, that does not answer my question. The question is why my ClusterIP service is not accessible by name from *inside* the cluster, but outside a pod.

Comment: Adding to what @lukman asked, if you are trying to access service from worker nodes, then you need to expose it as NodePort.

`ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType.`